# Can changing constraints be used with the scikit-optimize API?

Tags: scikit-optimize

The canonical use case for scikit-optimize is an optimization objective given a fixed set of hyperparameters, where skopt is given full control to explore the space. However, one may wish to simultaneously *expose* a variable to skopt and *fix it* to a certain value on a subsequent iteration because it is outside of one's control. **Is this possible using the current API?**

Hypothetical use case:

We wish to maximize bike sale profit. Price is a free parameter to be optimized. The rain forecast is outside of our control, but we wish to control for it in skopt.

Comment: Does this example help: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/interruptible-optimization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-interruptible-optimization-py. It looks like you could stop the search, adjust the parameter and then continue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The trick here is that we want to be able to still inform skopt of prior trials without throwing out any X containing values outside of the parameter space that is permitted by skopt. I believe a custom implementation is necessary, as skopt would complain that some inputs in X are outside of the input space if one changes the space on subsequent iterations.

Comment: I'd posed the question in different terms here: https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/944

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/pull/971